# Adding label on Edges in GraphSharp

Tags: vb.net, graph-sharp

I'm Using Graph# in VB.net i can easily add nodes and edges in it but how can i add labels on these edges ?? **can anybody help ...**

here's my codes to add nodes and edges

```
Dim g = New CompoundGraph(Of Object, IEdge(Of Object))()

Dim vertices = New String(29) {}
   For i As Integer = 0 To 29
      vertices(i) = i.ToString()
      g.AddVertex(vertices(i))
   Next i
```

And

```
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(0), vertices(1)))
```

Comment: Badvao javab na aavde to negative vote na karay

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim g = New BidirectionalGraph(Of Object, IEdge(Of Object))()

'add the vertices to the graph
Dim vertices As String() = New String(4) {}
For i As Integer = 0 To 4
   vertices(i) = i.ToString()
   g.AddVertex(vertices(i))
Next

'add some edges to the graph
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(0), vertices(1)))
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(1), vertices(2)))
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(2), vertices(3)))
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(3), vertices(1)))
g.AddEdge(New Edge(Of Object)(vertices(1), vertices(4)))

_graphToVisualize = g
```

Comment: I don't see how this adds labels to the edge?